# What To Do With Data Where All Records of Pseudoreplication are Lost?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, independence

So, I have what seems to me a slightly sticky situation and I've really no idea how to tackle this.  I've been asked to analyse the data on a fairly large project, but I can't see how it can be done as there is key information about pseudoreplication that is missing.  I will make an example that has similar qualities, but totally different details, to disguise the project, as a *lot* of time, money and effort has been spent on this.

Let's say, their experiment involves chopping up earthworms and testing for variable $y$ under different values of variable $x$.  At each $x$ value they test a bunch of earthworm samples for $y$.  But for some $x$ values, they used samples all cut from the same earthworm, and for others, the samples came from a mixture of multiple earthworms.  This is where I would think, great -- mixed model -- worm is a random factor.

But they didn't keep track of which earthworm went into which sample, so we have no idea which samples are repeated and which not.  My gut feeling (though I'm not the expert in this field) is that $y$ is probably going to be influenced by the particular earthworm we are dealing with.  But I can't be totally sure.

We do know that no earthworm could have been shared across different values of $x$.

Is there anything I can do with this data?  I initially thought that if we just assume that we use the same earthworm in each condition we would have something conservative.  ($x$ is a continuum, so we can have multiple samples across the continuum of $x$ even with just one worm per $x$).  However, I'm starting to wonder if that's right, because I think that counting the mean of multiple worms as if it were the mean of one leads to worm-random-effects that are smaller than they should be (as a low worm can cancel a high one).  So, then, it feels like that can't be conservative as it takes us closer to the zero-SD case where we get the same results as for iid data?

But am I right about that or is my thinking flawed?  Is there anything I can do with data like this?

Comment: If I understand your 'earthworm fable' correctly, one method is to randomly choose **one** of the multiple $y$ values at each $x.$ But that may result in too much loss of what might be 'information'. (You might weight resulting $y$'s inversely as the variance of the $y$'s at an $x.)$ // If you used the **mean** $y$ at each $x,$ then variances of the resulting $y$ would be unequal (to an unknowable extent). For many analyses that could be a serious departure from assumptions.

Comment: @BruceET thanks a lot for your thoughts!  You understand it perfectly.  I agree that randomly choosing one y is possibly the only "clean" option. (And completely understand your point about variances in the case of means -- I think that would be particularly a problem given that the sample size after averaging would then be fairly small). The only trouble with the "just pick one" option is the political aspect, when this data has been very expensive to obtain...  Argh!!

Comment: The political aspect certainly needs to be addressed. For now, maybe it would politically advantageous consistently to average two or three, hoping for minimal disruption (in the background checked against a parallel analysis using only one). For the future, maybe there is a diplomatic way to work toward a culture of more careful record keeping, especially for data that are expensive to obtain.

Comment: @BruceET Absolutely, I've already asked them to talk to me or to a statistician before embarking on their next endeavour.  (!)  I'll give your two or three idea some thought, it sounds quite sensible.  What I did so far was to run a simulation based on their data to see how much inferences would be affected by assigning all replicates at one x to the same random factor level (compared with correctly assigning the replicates).  Seemed fairly minimal, at least with the parameters I've chosen, so I'm hoping we might get away with that. (On the other hand, assuming iid was horrible unsurprisingly)